# Win 7 AHCI is Switching to Raid on reboot

Tags: windows-7, bios, ahci

I have a Dell Latitude E6440 that is switching back to raid despite being set to AHCI. The remaining Bios settings are staying as they should and once swapped back the laptop boots up as needed. Any ideas how i can stop it switching or rmeove raid permanently? I've checked the Cmos battery and this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

That should not happen, SATA port mode should be BIOS responsible alone, and not modified in any way by the operating system. If flipping it to raid mode it is a manufacturer choice, it will be probably hard to bypass it. Still, if you have installed intel SATA drivers and utilities (RST), I would advise reverting back to microsoft MSAHCI driver, and check if that helps. Properties of the SATA controller in device manager usually have some parameters to configure aswell.